# Close Magnific Popup Iframe when Clicking on Link

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup, magnific-popup

So right now I have a Magnific Popup iframe open to a form (using Machforms).

```
<div align="center">
  <a class="popup-link" href="...machform/view.php?id=3717">
     <img src="images/image.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

After submitting the form, it redirects to another iframe popup and has a link for a pdf download which opens in a new tab.

```
Thank you. Your submission has been successful! <br/>
<a href=".../downloads/TEST%20DOWNLOAD%20PAGE.pdf" target="_blank">Download file here.
</a>
```

Upon clicking, this 'download file here.' link, I would like it to automatically close the popup.

How would I go about doing this? I have tried closeOnContentClick and overriding the close, but I can't seem to get it to work for that specific link.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

You call `$.magnificPopup.close()` manually, but since it's in an `iframe` you need to call it from the parent window.

Here's what I did on an old project of mine

```
$('#yourlinkID').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (window.parent == window.top) {
      window.parent.$.magnificPopup.close();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add class .close-my-popup to your link and this to your javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
 $('.close-my-popup').click(function() {
    $.magnificPopup.close();
 });
});
```

Or you could do it like this:

```
<a href=".../downloads/example.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="$.magnificPopup.close();">Download file here.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach a click handler with javascript to that link, and then call window.close() for the callback.

Ex (with jQuery):

```
$('[link selector here]').click(function() {
    window.close();
});
```

Make sure this is added to the code in the iFrame, otherwise it will close your main window.

Comment: What do you mean by [link selector here]? 
would this be going into my javascript code for the magnific popup?
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This would be added to the Javascript within the pop-up. You could add the link selector $('a') in jQuery. Or you could add a class to the link and use the selector for that: ex: $('.close') and add class='close' to your link